# Is there an R function for taking the first four characters in a column and putting them into a new column?

Tags: r, split

I have different/non-repeating years at the beginning of a column (Details) in my data frame (Data) that I would like to split off and create a "Years" Column with. Based on other questions that have been answered, I am assuming I would use tstrsplit. However, I don't understand how to actually use the function to get it to do what I want.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

When you want characters from a fixed position within the string (like the first 4 characters) `substr` is quick and easy.

```
Data$Years = substr(Data$Details, 1, 4)
```

`strsplit` needs something to split at, so if you had `"2020-04-02"` you could split at `"-"` characters. But if you know you want the first four, `substr` is best.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks. I did Data$Years = substr(Data$Details, 1, 4) and got me the Years column. However, those 4 characters are still in the Details column. What would be the best thing to use to remove them?

Comment: Use `substr` again to remove them. `Data$Details = substr(Data$Details, start = 5, stop = 1000)` (pick some value for `stop` that is longer than the longest string. If you want to be fancy, `stop = nchar(Data$Details)`)